# Launch Firefox from Finder with logging modules

Tags: firefox, logging, environment-variables

I have found this site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/HTTP_logging

My problem is: The settings for about:networking only work for the current session. And I have no interest to always start Firefox from the console. Is there a way to launch Firefox (under Mac OS X) via Finder and to permanently enable those logging features?

BG

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Mac user, so this might be not the best way. However, you might try using an approach similar to running Firefox with multiple profiles, as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiple_profiles) on MDN. It suggests creating an *Automator* application that runs a shell script. You can follow [this](http://sonnygill.net/mac/mac-multiple-firefox-profiles/) guide, which tells you to:

- Open *Automator*
- Go to `File->New->Application`
- Choose `Utilities` group under `Library`
- Drag `Run Shell Script` to the workflow pane on the right
- Paste the script used to run Firefox with logging enabled
- Choose `Save As` and store it somewhere

You should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, but I just wanted to enable those variables when I normally start Firefox without any scripts involved.